# Building a Menu with anchor links as second menu level

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am working on a menu, showing the first level as normal links. The second menu level should be build as anchor menu from the content elements. Inspired by [this post](http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/menues/100408/) I build the following ts:

```
lib.footerMenu = HMENU
lib.footerMenu {
1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
    noBlur = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
        ATagParams = class="first" |*| |*| class="last"
        after.cObject = CONTENT
        after.cObject {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = this
                orderBy = sorting
                where = colPos=1
                languageField = sys_language_uid
            }
            wrap = <ul>|</ul>
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                field = header   
                dataWrap = <li><a href="#c{field:uid}">|</a></li>
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

producing something like that ('Arnold ipsum.' and 'Who the hell are you.' being CEs of the Homepage):

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="/" class="first">Homepage</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#c1">Arnold ipsum.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c11">Who the hell are you.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="team/">Team</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#c1">Arnold ipsum.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c11">Who the hell are you.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The problem now is, that *this* (pidInList = this) always holds the actual page id and so the anchor menu of the actual page is appended to all main menu items.

How to show the right anchor menu below every main menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lib.footerMenu = HMENU
lib.footerMenu {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
    noBlur = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
      ATagParams = class="first" |*| |*| class="last"
      after.cObject = CONTENT
      after.cObject {
        table = tt_content
        select {
          pidInList.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
          pidInList.stdWrap.cObject {
            key.field = doktype

            default = TEXT
            default.field = uid

            4 = TEXT
            4.field = shortcut
          }
          orderBy = sorting
          where = colPos=1
          languageField = sys_language_uid
          selectFields = uid,pid,header
        }
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
          field = header
          typolink {
            parameter.field = pid
            section.field = uid
          }
          wrap = <li>|</li>
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Though, it might not work on old TYPO3 installations because if I remember correctly `pidInList` didn't used to have `stdWrap`. It should work on TYPO3 4.5+.

Comment: I've extended the code as I realized that the anchors would be still wrong as they would be for the current page instead of the target page.

Comment: Your solution works nearly perfect.Is there a way to make it work with shortcuts too? My 'Homepage' is a shortcut and there are no CEs on it. Those should be fetched from the real home page.

Comment: There is still another problem, as the anchors are pointing to the current page instead of the page where the CEs are really on. I guess i would have to add something to the 'dataWrap = <li><a href="#c{field:uid}">|</a></li>' as well!?

Comment: The local links I have already changed before. Though, I wonder if they are correct, that is whether they are `#c1` or just `#1`.

Comment: As for the shortcut pages, I've added something that might be enough for you but which is not really universal solution because it doesn't take into account shortcut mode and also doesn't resolve nested shortcuts (page being a shortcut to another shorcut page). I now wonder whether there is an easy way to resolve shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, now i can see your edit! Works like a charm, links are correct (including #) and the CEs of shortcuts targets are shown. As i have no nested shortcuts, i am perfectly fine with that. I just added ' AND sectionIndex!=0' to take the 'Show in Section Menus' option into account. Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: You are welcome. I tried to find simple solution to resolving shortcuts so that this answer can be more useful for someone else as well but I haven't found any so **to make it better** `pidInList.stdWrap.cObject.4` would have to be changed to `CASE` as well and correct target page would have to be resolved for each shortcut type.